# Excel check for value in different cells per row

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

Having this kind of data:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
1   1   0   1   0   0
2   0   1   1   0   1
3   1   0   1   1   0
4   0   1   0   1   0
```

I would like to show true/false in column F if column A, C and E has the value of 1.

So not looking for a value in range - but different columns.

Comment: You mean if A1=1 & C1=1 & E1=1? And then A2=1 .... etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `AND` function, something like:

=IF(AND(A1=1,C1=1,E1=1),"TRUE","FALSE")

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(A2;IF(C2;IF(E2;TRUE;FALSE);FALSE);FALSE)`

This will display TRUE if ALL three cells are 1, else FALSE.